# What does it actually means - Use created + activated for keep-alive components in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, keep-alive

Initially, I am fetching data from `api` in the `created` hook which is perfectly working.

```
created() {
    this.fetchInformation()
}
```

But I was having look over best practices for lifecycle hooks and I came to this line  **You need to fetch some data for your component on initialization. Use created (or created + activated for keep-alive components)**

I also tried to look for relevant articles or information on the internet.

Url for reference - https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/

My component is rendering inside `keep-alive` so I tried this for the test purpose.

```
activated() {
    this.fetchInformation()
}
```

Instead of `created`, now as expected everytime the `component` activates it execute the `api` call which is really cool. But I still want to understand what this actually `created + activated` as I am using `activated` or `created` but if I am correct just by reading that I should do them both.

Please let me know if anything else required to understand my question.

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look some docs (cookbook)[https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html#Alternative-Patterns], (keep-alive)[https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive]. Activated is only called when the keep-alive component is `active` again.

Comment: Thank you for the response, But I already had a look on every possible doc available related to - `keep-alive`. Still I am just figuring how both created and keep-alive works together

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "work together"?

Comment: That's a typo - I meant as the title of the question, how can I use `created` + `activated` . If u see the bolded text in my question.That is what I actually trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Use correctly keep-alive!!

Incorrect:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="canRender">
      <keep-alive>
        <my-component />
      </keep-alive>
    </div>
  </div>
<template>
```

Incorrect:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <keep-alive>
      <div v-if="canRender">
        <my-component />
      </div>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
<template>
```

Correct:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <keep-alive>
        <my-component v-if="canRender" />
      </keep-alive>
    </div>
  </div>
<template>
```